# Is there a way to concretely know what files have been staged in the index matching the current commit?

Tags: git, indexing, commit, git-ls-files

Whether we use checkout or reset, when we jump from commit to commit, the index keeps matching the now-current commit.

When I ask people how to see what files are staged in the index for the now-current commit, they tell me: `git ls-files -s`

But `git ls-files -s` does not seem to be what I am looking for.
**This command just lists the tracked files of a sub-tree with the current directory being the root of it. If I move to another directory, the output of `git ls-files -s` changes!**

Really, is there a command out there that will solidly give me the tracked files for a commit after I jump from some other commit to it?

Comment: What is the importance of "after I jump from some other commit to it"? I mean, the list of tracked files for a particular commit does not change whether you jump from a commit to it or whether you just cloned a repository, or whatever reason lets you check out a certain commit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this a lot you could put something like this in a shell function or script.

```
git ls-files --full-name -s "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"
```

Comment: From your description, listing files staged in the index, `ls-files` is the correct command but it is, by design, context sensitive like `diff`. if you want the behavior where the output doesn't depend on the particular subdirectory then you need to script around this.

Comment: Or, use `git -C $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) ls-files -s`: same basic idea, we run the command at the top level (instead of "as if at the top level").